# Affix not working properly on Bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have used custom affix for a element on bootstrap profile tab. The problem is that the affix is working properly only if the tab is in active on document load. Otherwise its not working properly. But i want the first tab should be active on load. If i click the second tab(profile), the affix should work properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var offset = $(".pagination").offset();
  var top = offset.top - 42;
  /* alert(top); */

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > top) {
      $(".pagination").addClass("affix");
    } else {
      $(".pagination").removeClass("affix");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.affix {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 42px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
}

body {
  padding-top: 42px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bassjobsen/affix/master/assets/js/affix.js"></script>
<nav class="fixed-top" style="background:#fff;">
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
    <nav aria-label="page navigation">
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-0">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">9</a></li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `offset` and `top` on tab change event to get appropriate values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var offset = $(".pagination").offset();
  var top = offset.top - 42;
  /* alert(top); */

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > top) {
      $(".pagination").addClass("affix");
    } else {
      $(".pagination").removeClass("affix");
    }
  });

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab  
    offset = $(".pagination").offset();
    top = offset.top - 42;
  });
});
```

```css
.affix {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 42px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
}

body {
  padding-top: 42px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bassjobsen/affix/master/assets/js/affix.js"></script>
<nav class="fixed-top" style="background:#fff;">
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
    <nav aria-label="page navigation">
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-0">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">9</a></li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam auctor rutrum felis, non fermentum sem pulvinar in. Duis pulvinar, tellus vel suscipit suscipit, sem tortor tristique nisi, vitae pellentesque sapien dolor ut metus. Curabitur a sodales risus.
      Duis luctus lectus sit amet scelerisque aliquam. Nunc nec lectus congue ex eleifend tempus. Praesent et varius odio, sed egestas sapien. Sed quis molestie justo. Aliquam ut turpis pretium nunc tempor ornare in a est. Mauris tristique tincidunt purus,
      at laoreet quam vehicula a. Nunc vel consequat nunc, eget ullamcorper augue. Nunc lobortis, sapien vitae eleifend bibendum, libero nisl congue justo, non vestibulum lectus libero nec nulla. Suspendisse ac elit pulvinar, pellentesque magna ac, venenatis
      elit. Vivamus eget pellentesque nisl, eu sollicitudin lorem. Fusce convallis orci a blandit commodo. Nulla at luctus tortor.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi the affix is not working properly after  i scroll the first tab.